# How to calculate budget remaining for a budget used in multiple line items in Knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a Purchase Order model. Purchase order has Line Items.
Line Items have a budget.

Now whenever a user selects a budget from a budget dropdown list, using kncokoutjs I want to load the budget remaining amount from the server and then recalculate the remaining amount for that budget if items use the budget and display it under item.

My problem is how to design the model so that I can capture the budget selected on items and calculate the remaining amount.

[image]

Comment: Not sure why I cannot edit the question. Sorry for the spelling mistake. just to clarify that multiple items can use same budget.

Comment: obviously you gave us  very little to go on would be much better if you provided your code,  better yet a small reproducible example. however just reading your question I would say on change event on the dropdown list calls an ajax function that refreshes whatever it is you want from the server then for your calculation use a knockout computed function

Comment: Thanks Bryan. As the same budget can be used by multiple items, I do not know how to design the model to keep track of a selected budget on multiple items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make different ViewModels for a PurchaseOrder, an Item and a Budget. 
Use computeds to calculated the amounts
and use computeds for handling the ui (e.g. possible budgets).

(see http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html )

Code example in the snippet: (edit: implemented requirement that a budget can be used multiple times)

```js
// class for a budget
function Budget(purchaseOrder, name, amount) {
  // track the purchaseOrder object to be able to find the budgets that can be used
  var self = this;
  this.purchaseOrder = purchaseOrder
  this.name = name;

  // amount as an observable so it can be updated from the latest server state
  this.amount = ko.observable(amount);

  this.usedByItems = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    var returnValue = 0;
    self.purchaseOrder.items().forEach(function(item) {

      if (item.budget() === self && item.amount()) {
        // note:better type conversion required
        returnValue = returnValue + parseInt(item.amount());
      }


    });
    return returnValue;
  }, this);

  this.remaining = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return this.amount() - this.usedByItems();
  }, this);

  // use a computed to determine if the budget is used
  // in the final solutions, computed can be used in the budget dropdown to select only unused budgets
  this.used = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return this.purchaseOrder.isBudgetUsed(this);
  }, this);
}

// class for an item
function Item(purchaseOrder, budget) {

  var self = this;

  // track the purchase order to track the selectable budgets for the dropdown
  this.purchaseOrder = purchaseOrder;

  // computes the selectable budgets
  this.selectableBudgets = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    var returnValue = [];
    self.purchaseOrder.budgets.forEach(function(budget) {
      // add buget if the item's budget is the same, this to prevent budgets
      // magically disappearing from the dropdown
      if (budget === self.budget() || budget.remaining() > 0) {
        returnValue.push(budget);
      }
    });


    return returnValue;
  }, this);

  // computed to habdle a name when a budget is not selected
  this.name = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    if (this.budget()) {
      return this.budget().name;
    } else {
      return "(none)";
    }

  }, this);
  // the related budget
  this.budget = ko.observable(budget);

  // the entered amount
  this.amount = ko.observable();

}


// the main viewmodel
function PurchaseOrderViewModel() {
  // define the budgets, in the final situation it would probably an observable array so more budgets can be added
  this.budgets = [
    new Budget(this, "Budget 1", 20),
    new Budget(this, "Budget 2", 30),
    new Budget(this, "Budget 3", 40)
  ];

  // the items for the purchase order
  this.items = ko.observableArray(
    [
      new Item(this, this.budgets[0]),
      new Item(this, this.budgets[2]),
    ]
  );

  var self = this;



  this.addItem = function() {
    var item = new Item(self);
    self.items.push(item);
  }

  this.remove = function(item) {
    self.items.remove(item);

  }

  // determins if there is an item that uses the budget.
  this.isBudgetUsed = function(budget) {
    var returnValue = false;
    self.items().forEach(function(item) {
      if (item.budget() === budget) {
        returnValue = true;
      }
    });

    return returnValue;
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new PurchaseOrderViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script> 

<h1>
Items
</h1>
<ul data-bind="foreach:items">
  <li>
    <select data-bind="options:selectableBudgets,optionsText:'name',value:budget,optionsCaption:'(select a budget)'">

    </select>
    <span data-bind="text:name"></span>
    <input data-bind="value:amount" type="number" />
    <a href="javascript:void();" data-bind="click:function(){ $parent.remove($data);}">remove</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<a href="javascript:void();" data-bind="click:addItem">add item</a>

<h1>
Budget
</h1>
<ul data-bind="foreach:budgets">
  <li>

    <span data-bind="text:name"></span> #<span data-bind="text:amount"></span>, used in po:<span data-bind="text:used"></span>, amount used:<span data-bind="text:usedByItems"></span>, remaining:<span data-bind="text:remaining"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to implement the solution. I have a bit different models but the solution you provided gives me an idea to implement same budget used on multiple items and get the budget totals.